# Using Excel to generate a Visio diagram - using 'select' method in IF statement

Tags: vba, visio, visual-studio-macros

I am currently integrating Excel with Visio to auto-populate some elements diagrammatically. I have got so far with this effort but have got stuck between the documentation, macro recordings and actually doing what I want.

By recording macros I have found a way of selecting individual elements like so:
`ActiveWindow.Select Application.ActiveWindow.Page.Shapes.ItemFromID(216), visSelect`

I have a loop in my script as follows:

```
For Each oItem In vsoDocument.Pages(sitePage).Shapes
    If oItem.Name <> "Sheet.2" Then
        'vsoDocument.Pages(sitePage).Select oItem.Item, visSelect ' NOW REMOVED
        oItem.DeleteEx (visDeleteNormal)
        Debug.Print oItem.Name
    End If
Next oItem
```

UPDATE: Following from your responses and sanity checks you are right that I don't need to select the shape. I have amended the code to simply show `oItem.DeleteEx (visDeleteNormal)` now and this works as expected. However I am left with a number of shapes on my sheet, such as a shape with the name "Ethernet.46". I don't know why some shapes were deleted and also why the page background was removed. I've found if I run my For loop once, add the background back in WITH `vsoDocument.Pages(sitePage).BackPage`, then run my For loop again another 5 times in succession it finally removes all shapes.

QUESTION: Why is my For loop behaving unreliably?

Comment: Why are you using `oItem.Item` and not just `oItem` ?

Comment: Visio object model dox: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff765377.aspx

Comment: This is a shot in the dark, and maybe a little clunky, but try: `vsoDocument.Application.ActiveWindow.Select oItem, visSelect`

Comment: Also, it's not clear from the code you've provided: why do you need to `Select` the shape?  Usually this is not necessary...

Comment: when you edit a question, especially when you edit it in response to a comment or answer, you should probably mention/tag the person who answered already, otherwise we've no way of knowing you've made the revision.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> the .Select line fails, and I'm pretty sure it's the oItem.Item call that's failing as

The `Select` line fails because the `Page` object doesn't have a `Select` method. That pertains to the `Window` object. From the dox, it looks like `oItem.Item` will also fail, so you can probably just use the `oItem` which itself is a `Shape` object.

> What is the correct syntax for this command in this loop?

Possibly as follows:

```
vsoDocument.Application.ActiveWindow.Select oItem, visSelect
```

However, it's not clear from the code you've provided: **why do you need to `Select` the shape?** Usually this is not necessary. It may be possible to do what you're trying to do without relying on `Select` at all.

> Is there a way I could have fished for this information myself? e.g. can I reveal methods associated with the oItem definition, like "Name"?

You can view the properties associated with each object using the Locals pane in the VBE, and you can view properties & methods from either the documentation (which usually includes syntax examples & use) or from within the VBE press <kbd>F2</kbd> to bring up the Object Browser.

You can browse the Visio object model, here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff765377.aspx

Navigating that hierarchy, you can browse the events, properties and methods of the `Shape` object:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff768546.aspx

**Update**

ALWAYS when you are deleting elements from a collection, you must do this by index, and in reverse order.

```
Dim i as Long
For i = vsoDocument.Pages(sitePage).Shapes.Count to 1 Step - 1
    Set oItem = vsoDocument.Pages(sitePage).Shapes(i)
    If oItem.Name <> "Sheet.2" Then
        Debug.Print oItem.Name
        oItem.DeleteEx (visDeleteNormal)
    End If
Next oItem
```

The reason this is necessary, is that when you `Delete` an item, the collection re-indexes itself, so when you delete Item #1, then Item #2 becomes the first index, but your loop takes you to the *next* item, which is now Item #3.  Forcing the loop by index, and in reverse order, prevents this undesired behavior.